# Setup of UICollectionView in horizontal format with an array of images in different cells

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a collection view and I want to set five cells with images in them. We can capture the images from camera. I want the cells to be kept like in the horizontal format.

Here in the first image I add the imagePickerController to open the camera.

[a cell with the did select action of opening camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoaiT.png)

[each image captured should set in each cell like this!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymCPC.png)

[the 5th image should settle in place of the take photo cell!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw4Qh.png)

Also, these above images are just a design of how I wanna set the collection view to look in the end.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


//
let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
var items: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "user-icon")!,
    UIImage(named: "lock-icon")!,
    UIImage(named: "search.png")!
]
var imgPicker = UIImagePickerController()
//
//    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
//
//    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)
    {
        print(self.items[indexPath.row])
    }
    cell.imgPicker1.image = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

}

//MARK:- UI ImagePicker Delegate Methods


func openCamera(){
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera)) {
        let authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
        switch authStatus {
        case .authorized:
            showCamera()
        case .denied:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Alert!", comment: "") + " \n" + NSLocalizedString("Please enable the Permission for Camera", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("So that Group Icon can be set.", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), style: .default) { action in
                self.openSettingToEnableNotification()
            })
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video,
                                          completionHandler: { (granted:Bool) -> Void in
                                            if granted {
                                                print("access granted", terminator: "")
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                print("access denied", terminator: "")}
            })
        default:
            openSettingToEnableNotification()
        }
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("Device has no camera", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
        })
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
func openSettingToEnableNotification(){
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
}
func showCamera()           {if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera))
{
    imgPicker.delegate = self
    imgPicker.sourceType = .camera
    //imgPicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imgPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Warning", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("You don't have camera", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    openCamera()

}
}
```

Comment: What is problem you are facing in this?

Comment: See the images(just a demo design). I want to set the cells in that design. But the image doesn't show in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The member imgPicker1 of you custom Cell should be added to the cell, unless it’s just stores the images.
Provide us with the code of your cell and we can help.

In the Storyboard you can set the cell as your CollectionViewCell and Drag an UiImageView into it, which than is referenced in your class as a IBOutlet.